# Wordpress widget save

Tags: php, wordpress

I suddenly got this weird Wordpress problem when I click on save button in widget section. If I enter iframe code and click on save it will load infinitely but if I enter regular text like "hello" or other html tag like "" that will be saved.

Can someone help me with this? 
I've been making some changes in `functions.php` file but when I undo them problem is still there so I guess something else is broken.

Comment: typo, requires more info

Comment: This isn't necessarily a programming question. There is a blog directly for wordpress.. try here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Found a problem. Wordfence plugin is causing this mess.